# Is it possible for an Application to consume any Rss feed subscription request?

Tags: android, rss, intentfilter

I am developing an Android application that will "harvest" Rss subscriptions wherever the user selects one, e.g. from within the Android devices installed web browsers etc..

I thought all that was required was to define the correct intent filters within my application manifest file

I have the following

```
 <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <data android:scheme="feed" />
        <data android:scheme="rss" />
 </intent-filter>

 <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*xml"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*feed=rss"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*feed=atom"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*feed=rdf"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*feed.*"
            android:scheme="http" />
        <data
            android:host="*"
            android:pathPattern=".*rss.*"
            android:scheme="http" />
     </intent-filter>

     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
           <data
               android:mimeType="text/xml"
               android:scheme="http" />
           <data
               android:mimeType="application/rss+xml"
               android:scheme="http" />
           <data
               android:mimeType="application/rdf+xml"
               android:scheme="http" />
           <data
               android:mimeType="application/atom+xml"
               android:scheme="http" />
      </intent-filter>
```

When I test out clicking on the following rss feed link from within Chrome on my test device

http://www.tandfonline.com/action/showFeed?ui=0&mi=hph1f7&ai=109&jc=naqi20&type=etoc&feed=rss

The feed opens within Chrome instantly.

My application is ignored as a possible "target" for this link.

Is it possible for my application to register its availability to "consume" links such as this?

What Intent filters would I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible for my application to register its availability to "consume" links such as this?

Not universally. Let's review your current `<intent-filter>` setup with respect to this URL:

- The URL does not have an `rss` or `feed` scheme. AFAIK, those are not especially common schemes.
- The URL's path is `/action/showFeed`, which does not match any of your `pathPattern` values. There is no standardized path for feeds.
- This server uses a MIME type of `application/xml` (tested using `curl -v`), which is valid but fairly generic. You could add that MIME type to your roster, but you will be a candidate for other XML than feeds.